# HP LaserJet P1505 doesn't work after update to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp

My HP LaserJet P1505 doesn't work after update to Ubuntu 12.04 from 11.10. It's visible to applications and they see when printer is turned on and when doesn't. But when I'm printing any document I'm getting "Printer error" : "connecting-to-device" pop-up message and then "Printing complete" message.

In /var/log/syslog I have the following (please edit message if it goes against the rule to attach so long logs):

```
May  5 00:45:39 dmitriy-desktop hp-mkuri: io/hpmud/model.c 625: unable to find [s{product}] support-type in /usr/share/hplip/data/models/models.dat
May  5 00:45:41 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: Missing HP LaserJet P1505 firmware file /lib/firmware/hp/sihpP1505.dl
May  5 00:45:41 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: ...read foo2zjs installation instructions and run ./getweb P1505
May  5 00:45:42 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0
May  5 00:45:42 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2
May  5 00:45:42 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: Device vendor/product is 03F0:3F17
May  5 00:45:42 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: MFG:Hewlett-Packard MDL:HP LaserJet P1505 SERN:- serial:CA4118W
May  5 00:45:42 dmitriy-desktop kernel: [14955.846817] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 6 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x3F17
May  5 00:45:42 dmitriy-desktop kernel: [14955.846971] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
May  5 00:45:42 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/usb/lp0
May  5 00:45:43 dmitriy-desktop kernel: [14956.991611] usblp0: removed
May  5 00:45:43 dmitriy-desktop kernel: [14957.002692] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 6 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x3F17
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: URI contains USB serial number
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: URI match: usb://HP/LaserJet%20P1505?serial=CA4118W
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: SERN field matches USB serial number
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: URI match: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P1505?serial=CA4118W
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P1505?serial=CA4118W, normalized: laserjet p1505 serial ca4118w
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://HP/LaserJet%20P1505?serial=CA4118W, normalized: laserjet p1505 serial ca4118w
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost:631/printers/HP-LaserJet-P1505 has matching device URI
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: Device already handled
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: IPP-Resume-Printer request failed
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P1505?serial=CA4118W, normalized: laserjet p1505 serial ca4118w
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost:631/printers/HP-LaserJet-P1505 has matching device URI
May  5 00:45:44 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: IPP-Resume-Printer request failed
May  5 00:45:45 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: Missing HP LaserJet P1505 firmware file /lib/firmware/hp/sihpP1505.dl
May  5 00:45:45 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: ...read foo2zjs installation instructions and run ./getweb P1505
May  5 00:45:45 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: Missing HP LaserJet P1505 firmware file /lib/firmware/hp/sihpP1505.dl
May  5 00:45:45 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: ...read foo2zjs installation instructions and run ./getweb P1505
May  5 00:45:45 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/usb/lp0
May  5 00:45:45 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2
May  5 00:45:45 dmitriy-desktop udev-configure-printer: Device already handled
May  5 00:45:48 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: Missing HP LaserJet P1505 firmware file /lib/firmware/hp/sihpP1505.dl
May  5 00:45:48 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: ...read foo2zjs installation instructions and run ./getweb P1505
May  5 00:45:48 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: Missing HP LaserJet P1505 firmware file /lib/firmware/hp/sihpP1505.dl
May  5 00:45:48 dmitriy-desktop /usr/sbin/hpljP1505: foo2zjs: ...read foo2zjs installation instructions and run ./getweb P1505
May  5 00:51:54 dmitriy-desktop foo2xqx-wrapper: foo2xqx-wrapper -r1200x600 -p9 -T3 -m1 -s7 -d1 -n1
May  5 00:51:56 dmitriy-desktop foo2xqx-wrapper: gs -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -g9920x7016 -r1200x600 -sDEVICE=pbmraw -dCOLORSCREEN -dMaxBitmap=500000000  
May  5 00:51:56 dmitriy-desktop foo2xqx-wrapper: foo2xqx -r1200x600 -g9920x7016 -p9 -m1 -n1 -d1 -s7  -u 176x84 -l 176x84   -T3     
May  5 00:51:56 dmitriy-desktop kernel: [15329.392969] usblp0: removed
```

I wanted to install HPLIP from [hplipopensource.com](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html), but got answer that Ubuntu 12.04 already has the last HPLIP drivers for my model.

Another interesting thing is that before upgrade and in Windows 7 Tonner light and Ready light were on, but in 12.04 only Ready light is on.

Any ideas how to make my printer prints in 12.04?

Comment: Did you try running `hp-setup` to install a "plug-in?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your printer in the printer/CUPS panel. Then go to the ubuntu software center and install HPLIP. During that installation it will detect the printer and prompt you to download drivers directly from HP. DO SO. A reboot and you should be done.

Comment: Thanks! It still shows "Printing error" popup message, but it prints now!